# How to convert / encode a negative number as an immediate in MIPS machine code

Tags: binary, mips, twos-complement, machine-code, immediate-operand

I want to change this instruction to binary or machine code:
`addi $s3, $s1, -1000`.

I know how to encode the opcode, `rs`, and `rt`,  but I have no idea how to convert `-1000` to binary.

I know how to get 1's complement and 2's complement. But i don't know how to express it in this I type instruction.
I just don't know how to express -1000 into last 16 digits as binary number.

since 1000(decimal) is 0000001111101000 in 16 digit.

```
1's complement is      1111110000010111
                                     +1
=                      1111110000011000 2's complement
```

so the answer for the whole instruction is

```
001000 10001 10011 1111110000011000
addi    rs    rt     immediate
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, MIPS `addi` / `addiu`  use a 16-bit signed 2's complement immediate as the low 16 bits of the instruction word**.  The CPU will sign-extend it to 32 (or 64) bits when decoding.

But note that `ori` / `xori` / `andi` logical instruction use *unsigned* 16-bit immediates that are zero-extended to 32-bit (or 64-bit), so `-1000` is not encodable.

To implement `xori $t0, $t1, -1000`, you'd need to create a 32-bit `-1000` in a register with something like `addiu $at, $zero, -1000`, then you could `xori $t0, $t1, $at`.  (`$at` is the "assembler temporary" register that pseudo-instructions like `bgt` use.)